# how to make different shapes in winform like we draw in a paint?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to draw different shapes in windows form like we draw in a paint.
I want the scenario like when user click on rectangle button and then draws a rectangle on the form it should be drawn and so is the case for drawing freehand shape. The Following is my code:

```
    {
        bool shouldPaint = false;
        int initialX;
        int initialY;
        bool rectButton = false;
        bool freeButton = false;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            shouldPaint = true;
            initialX = e.X;
            initialY = e.Y;
        }

        private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            shouldPaint = false;
        }
        if ( (rectButton==true) && (shouldPaint))
            {
                //
                this.Invalidate();
              this.Refresh();
                System.Drawing.Pen pen1 = new          System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
                Graphics painter = CreateGraphics();
int width = e.X - initialX, height = e.Y - initialY;
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(initialX, initialY, width * Math.Sign(width), height * Math.Sign(height));
                painter.DrawRectangle(pen1, rect);


            }
            else if ((freeButton == true) && (shouldPaint))
            {
                //this.Refresh();
              //  this.Invalidate();
                Graphics painter = CreateGraphics();

                painter.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), e.X, e.Y, 4, 4);
```

I am facing two problems; the first is that I am able to draw my rectangle in the forward direction but when I try to draw it in backward direction it did not work.
Secondly when I click on freehand button then it do draw on the form as freehand shapes but when I first click on rectangle button and then click the freehand button it does not draw any freehand shape. 
I am a beginner so be gentle and help me please :)

Comment: Just swap initialX/Y with e.X/Y so you get a valid rectangle with a positive Width and Height.  Remove the Math.Sign hack, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

dont send initialX and initialY as the nstarting coordinates 
instead send :

```
int minX = Math.Min((int)initX, (int)e.X);
 int minY = Math.Min((int)initY, (int)e.Y);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(minX,minY width * Math.Sign(width), height * Math.Sign(height));
```